# AngularJS $http.get with ngRoute how to list details

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-http

Maybe someone will help me. I write an app in angularjs, I have a file named list.html which retrieves a list of posts from jsonplaceholder and lists them, with a link to the details of the post. In $ routeParams, I pass the id of the selected one and pick it up. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to download the details of a post and display them in the details.html file. If I want to remove something for example, I write for example $ scope.deletePost as a function and give an id, but how to list details I have no idea.

//routing.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"])
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test', {
                templateUrl: '/event/example.html',
                controller: 'exampleController'
            }, null)
            .when('/list', {
                templateUrl: '/event/list.html',
                controller: 'exampleController'
            }, null)
            .when('/test-list', {
                templateUrl: '/test/list.html',
                controller: 'testController'
            }, null)
            .when('/test/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/test/details.html',
                controller: 'testController'
            }, null)
    }
]);
```

//controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('testController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data;
    });

    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;


});
```

//details.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="testController">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

//list.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="testController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
          Tytuł: {{post.title}} <a href="#!test/{{post.id}}" >Show</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aVMEHK?p=preview).

You just need to pass the details using `ng-href` and then catch in the controller using `$routeParams`. I hope this would help you with what you were looking for.

```
var app  = angular.module( 'mainApp', ['ngRoute'] );

 app.config( function( $routeProvider ) {

 $routeProvider
 .when( '/main', {
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: 'listCtrl'
  })
  .when('/detail/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    controller: 'detailCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/main'
  });
});

app.controller( 'listCtrl', function( $scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.data = res.data;
    })

});

app.controller( 'detailCtrl', function( $scope,$http, $routeParams) {
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
   $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+$scope.id)
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.data = res.data;
    })
});
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks :)